# Triggering intent in Dialogflow?(Using V2 api)

Tags: dialogflow-es

How to trigger an intent in Dialogflow?I need to trigger an intent without response from user. I know we need to call an event here, but don't know how to do the same in V2 api?

Comment: Some more info might help such as - what is the use case ? what do you mean by 'without response from user' ? Does it mean, the intent should trigger at the beginning, or just in between the conversation ?!!

Answer (score -1):

You trigger event from dialogflow, it's as easy to `detectIntent`

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const config = require('../config');
// Import the JSON to gRPC struct converter

const credentials = {
    client_email: config.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    private_key: config.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
};

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(
    {
        projectId: config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
        credentials
    }
);


module.exports = {

    async sendEventToDialogFlow(event, params = {}) {
        const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID, sessionId);
        const request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
                event: {
                    name: event,
                    languageCode: config.DF_LANGUAGE_CODE,
                },
            }
        };
        const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
        return responses[0].queryResult;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is completely wrong. Dialogflow exposes a normal [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview), at no point do users have to use gRPC, especially not with homegrown converter functions.

Comment: i agree with you but if you need to trigger event from backend with dialogflow module this is the way, OP is not asking for rest api calls

Comment: No this is not the way, you can just specify the event params like any other JS object. That the API doc says "struct format" means only that is has to be a <string, value> map, it does not mean that you have to convert anything manually.